# yes takes CPU usage to 99%

Tags: macbook-pro, cpu

Running `yes > /dev/null` takes my CPU usage to 99%.

[image: Activity monitor]

The Macbook Air 2018 have a 2 core CPU (1.6 GHz Core i5 [I5-8210Y]). Why is the "% CPU" taken by this process so high?

Comment: What did you expect? It just dumps data into the void, so the process doesn’t have to wait for disk IO, display updates or similar.

Comment: This is expected behaviour from `yes`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because Activity Monitor displays CPU usage as a percentage of a single core. So 100% means that one core is fully occupied.

The percentage can thus be higher than 100% when a program utilizes multiple cores.

The “yes” program is designed to use only one core, and use it fully. Therefore the behavior you’re seeing is entirely normal.